# How do I match users permission with all the permissions in the database

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to get the user role with permissions and compare them with all permissions that are in the database, if they match then a checkbox should be checked... I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly

**RoleController** :

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $role =Role::where('id', $id)->with('permissions')->first();
    $permissions = Permission::all();
    return view('admin.roles.edit', compact('role', 'permissions'));
}
```

**edit.blade.php** :

```
<table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">TYPE</th>
            <th scope="col">CREATE</th>
            <th scope="col">VIEW</th>
            <th scope="col">UPDATE</th>
            <th scope="col">DELETE</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($permissions as $permission)
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox ml-3">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="{{ $permission->name }}" value="{{ ($permission->name) }}" {{ ($permission->name == "$role->permissions->name") ? "checked" : "" }}>
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{ $permission->name }}">{{ $permission->display_name }}</label>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm not getting any errors but I cant make the checkbox to be checked if they match... I'm using Laratrust 5.2

Comment: Inside your `@foreach` make sure that `$permission->name` and `$role->permissions->name` are actually the same (check for case and whitespace). Use `dump($permission->name)` and `dump($role->permissions->name)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this,

```
    @foreach($permissions as $permission)
    @php
    $attribute = ($permission->id === $role->permissions->id) 
        ? 'checked="checked"'
        : '';
    @endphp
    <label for="permission-{{ $permission->id }}">
        <input type="checkbox" {{ $attribute }} class="custom-control-input" id="permission-{{ $permission->id }}" value="{{ ($permission->id) }}"> 
        <span>{{ ($permission->name) }}</span>
    </label>
    @endforeach
```

`$permissions` and `$role->permissions` should share the `id` field with same integer value where applicable.

I've added some extra html as it's considered as a good practice and changed your id & value attributes so it becomes more precise & standard.